# js-routes adding (::format) to urls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, js-routes

I have a simple rails project that I've been playing around in with reactjs. To add some basic navigation, I brought the js-routes library in and it works great for urls that have a path parameter such as "localhost:3000/addresses/1".

The problem I am facing is I am trying to call a "new" resource method and it adds the (::format) literally to the url which of course bombs as localhost:3000/addresses/new(.:format) is an invalid path.

I reference the "new_address_path" path as specified in the routes-js docs. The rake output for this url is below:

```
new_address_path    GET /addresses/new(.:format)    addresses#new
```

The HTML snippet utilizing the above path looks like this:

```
<a href={Routes.new_address_path}>Create am address</a>
```

ENV:

```
-Ruby: 2.2.4
-Rails: 4.2.6
-js-routes: 1.2.8
```

Route in question:

```
resources :addresses
```

What am I missing here? It seems like it is not interpreting the rails route file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I thought I posted my solution in here.

The problem wasn't js-routes but rather my AJAX call, I was setting the content type to JSON and I assumed that it was converting my object to JSON using the built in methods. This is not true, you need to manually convert the object to JSON via JSON.stringify(obj).

Old ajax call:

```
....
url: Routes.feedback_path(),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
type: 'POST',
data: obj,
....
```

New ajax call:

```
....
url: Routes.feedback_path(),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question. If you want to generate url with format suffix you can use `format` option in the helper method. For example:

```
Routes.new_address_path(format: 'js')
```

will generate something like this:

```
/addresses/new.js
```

Comment: Sorry. I meant, my route is using the default rails route type of "resource" which automatically appends a (::format) to the end of the URLs so that it can accept different formats. When working in ERB files, I do not have to specify a format, rails figures out whether it's html/json etc. I would expect the same behaviour from js-routes, am I mistaken? I could pass the format but it seems like a waste. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You might have found a solution, but your original problem *is* one with `js-routes`, or rather your use of it.

You have to provide the parens to get the correct output from js-routes.

Original: `Routes.new_address_path`

Fixed: `Routes.new_address_path()`

As smefju posted, you can specify the format in the parens, but completely leaving them off is not an option.